# jquery.maskMoney e jquery.mask inseridos no mesmo arquivo: conflito

Tags: javascript, jquery

tenho **2** **campos** no **form**:

```
<input type="text" name="telefone" id="telefone" required maxlength="14" />
```

e

```
<input type="text" id="valor" name="valor" required class="real"  />
```

O primeiro usa `jquery.mask` e o segundo `jquery.maskMoney`

Está dando **conflito**.

Existe algum *recurso* para isso?

Se eu deixar o `jquery.mask`o `jquery.maskMoney` não funciona e vice-versa.

Exste algum **plugin** que faça as **2** *funções*?

Comment: Já tentou trocar a ordem na hora de importar?

Comment: não, vou testar

Comment: funcionou! Obrigado amigo!